# import module without nodejs - vanillaJS

Tags: javascript, module

I'm refreshing my old and low knowledge on VanillaJS using the latest best practices i found.
I recently did a tutorial on NodeJS doing API REST with ExpressJs and one with Socket IO.
Now I want to practice a little before going to REACTJS.
So I started a little project
I do one without NodeJs - just JS into HTML view - using Objects.
I want to use modules from Npm. I want to try Fakerjs but when i want to import it i have a 403.
The path is correct, no error.

So i'm wondering if it's possible without Nodejs to import modules when doing VanillaJs?
Am i doing it wrong ?

The structure of the project is :

```
 js/
   main.js
   class/
 node_modules/
 index.html
```

Main.js:

```
'use strict'
//Importation of modules
import faker from '../node_modules/faker'

//Importation of Class Folder
import { Crypto } from "./class/crypto.class.js";
console.log(faker);
faker.locale = 'en_US';
```

I have this error in console:
*GET http://crypto-market-js.local:8282/node_modules/faker/ net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)*

If i write : import faker from 'faker' (like with node js but it's a require instead) i have this : *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "faker". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"*.

If you could give me a hand on that plz :)

Comment: ES6 module specifiers as currently implemented in browser must point to the module file itself, not to a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to import with `require` is **not supported** without NodeJS, because `require` is a node-specific function. When trying to import modules into Vanilla JS, my recommendation is to first link to ths script with the `<script>` html tag, and then add another script with `import faker from 'faker'`

Hope that clarifies your issue.